# System.InvalidOperationException when running .NET MVC project on Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to import our project developed in Visual Studio 2017 Community to Visual Studio for Mac. Everything appears to be working in terms of building the project and propagating the data in the database, however when it comes to displaying the CSHTMl page it throws the following exception:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException
    The view found at '~/Views/Account/login.cshtml' was not created.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Web.Mvc.
Exception stack trace:
  at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render (System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext viewContext, System.IO.TextWriter writer) [0x00061] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context) [0x00080] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] filters, System.Int32 filterIndex, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext preContext, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x0000b] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] filters, System.Int32 filterIndex, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext preContext, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x0009b] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] filters, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x0000a] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass21+<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c () [0x0008a] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00041] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResult`1[TResult].CallEndDelegate (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End () [0x00029] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult] (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Web.Mvc.Controller+ExecuteCoreState innerState) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Web.Mvc.Async.EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1[System.Web.Mvc.Controller+ExecuteCoreState]:invoke_void_IAsyncResult_TState (System.IAsyncResult,System.Web.Mvc.Controller/ExecuteCoreState)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncVoid`1[TState].CallEndDelegate (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End () [0x00029] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult] (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15 (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Web.Mvc.Controller controller) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncVoid`1[TState].CallEndDelegate (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End () [0x00029] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult] (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5 (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler+ProcessRequestState innerState) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Web.Mvc.Async.EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1[System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler+ProcessRequestState]:invoke_void_IAsyncResult_TState (System.IAsyncResult,System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler/ProcessRequestState)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncVoid`1[TState].CallEndDelegate (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End () [0x00029] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult] (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.async_handler_complete_cb (System.IAsyncResult ar) [0x00015] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:988
```

I've read that it's due to the Views/Web.config file incorrectly referencing the version of MVC however it is correctly pointing to version 5.2.3.0. Anyone else run into this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer to the problem - it turns out it was merely due to a capitalisation issue in the URL - the URL was pointing to http://localhost:8080/Account/login as opposed to http://localhost:8080/Account/Login. Apparently on PC this isn't an issue but on linux based system capitalisation is an issue. In my case the change was made in Web.config at the following location:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login">
```